# What is the best way to encode string by public-key in python

Tags: python, public-key-encryption, private-key, pycrypto

Is there any way to encode string by public-key?

I found two packages, pycrypto and m2crypto.
But I can not find how to use them.

Comment: You don't "encode" with public keys, you encrypt (usually). Also, what kind of public key? There are several implementations out there.

Comment: Read the pycrypto documentation: https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/.

Comment: related: [How to encrypt a string using the key](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1320671/4279)

Answer (score 1):

To encode a string using public key:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
from M2Crypto import RSA, X509

x509 = X509.load_cert("recipient_cert.pem")
rsa = x509.get_pubkey().get_rsa()
print rsa.public_encrypt("your string to encrypt", RSA.pkcs1_oaep_padding)
```