# How to implement OpenSSL functionality in Python?

Tags: python, openssl, public-key-encryption, private-key

I would like to encrypt a secret text by public-key and decrypt it by private-key in Python.
I can achieve that with the `openssl` command:

```sh
echo "secrettext/2011/09/14 22:57:23" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.pem | base64  data.cry
base64 -D data.cry | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.pem
```

How would one implement that in Python?

Answer (score 21):

#### Encrypt

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
from M2Crypto import RSA

rsa = RSA.load_pub_key("public.pem")
ctxt = rsa.public_encrypt(fileinput.input().read(), RSA.pkcs1_oaep_padding)
print ctxt.encode('base64')
```

#### Decrypt

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
from M2Crypto import RSA

priv = RSA.load_key("private.pem")
ctxt = fileinput.input().read().decode('base64')
print priv.private_decrypt(ctxt, RSA.pkcs1_oaep_padding)
```

#### Dependencies:

- [M2Crypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto) (seems to be Python 2 only)

See also [How to encrypt a string using the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320671/how-to-encrypt-a-string-using-the-key/1480597#1480597) and [What is the best way to encode string by public-key in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563732/what-is-the-best-way-to-encode-string-by-public-key-in-python).

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way to get exactly the same behaviour would be using [pyOpenSSL](https://launchpad.net/pyopenssl) - it's a thin Python wrapper for OpenSSL itself.

Comment: a code sample would be great; the docs on pyopenssl are quite a bit more opaque.

Answer (score 1):

The [m2crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto) module(s) expose much of OpenSSL's functionality to Python, including public/private encryption, decryption, and signing.

Most Linux distribution provide the m2crypto module as a native package.

Comment: thanks. I know that module. But I can't write that code using m2crypto. Could you tell me information with more specific function ?

Comment: Show me what you've tried and what sort of errors you're getting and I would be happy to help out.