# RSA encryption and decryption in Python

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, pycrypto

I need help using RSA encryption and decryption in Python.

I am creating a private/public key pair, encrypting a message with keys and writing message to a file. Then I am reading ciphertext from file and decrypting text using key.

I am having trouble with the decryption portion. As you can see in my code below, when I put in `decrypted = key.decrypt(message)` that the program works, yet the decrypted message is encrypted again. It seems like it is not reading the ciphertext from the file.

Can anyone help me write this code so decryption reads ciphertext from file and then uses key to decrypt ciphertext?

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator) #generate public and private keys

publickey = key.publickey # pub key export for exchange

encrypted = publickey.encrypt('encrypt this message', 32)
#message to encrypt is in the above line 'encrypt this message'

print 'encrypted message:', encrypted #ciphertext

f = open ('encryption.txt', 'w'w)
f.write(str(encrypted)) #write ciphertext to file
f.close()

#decrypted code below

f = open ('encryption.txt', 'r')
message = f.read()

decrypted = key.decrypt(message)

print 'decrypted', decrypted

f = open ('encryption.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(message))
f.write(str(decrypted))
f.close()
```

Comment: *I am having trouble with the decryption portion* is not a good description of your problem. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should [edit] your question to include your inputs, outputs and your expected outputs.

Comment: The edit helped, but it would still help if you included the output of your program, and the output you expect

Comment: You have multiple typos in your code. So what did you actually try?

Comment: Bear in mind that this is ["Textbook RSA"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/definition-of-textbook-rsa) which is **weak**, especially for short messages. Padding (via PKCS#1) remedies these problems which PyCrypto (and PyCryptodome, the maintained fork) can do.

Comment: related: [How to encrypt a string using the key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1320671/4279)

Answer (score 55):

In order to make it work you need to convert key from str to tuple before decryption(ast.literal_eval function). Here is fixed code:

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
import ast

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator) #generate pub and priv key

publickey = key.publickey() # pub key export for exchange

encrypted = publickey.encrypt('encrypt this message', 32)
#message to encrypt is in the above line 'encrypt this message'

print('encrypted message:', encrypted) #ciphertext
f = open ('encryption.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(encrypted)) #write ciphertext to file
f.close()

#decrypted code below

f = open('encryption.txt', 'r')
message = f.read()


decrypted = key.decrypt(ast.literal_eval(str(encrypted)))

print('decrypted', decrypted)

f = open ('encryption.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(message))
f.write(str(decrypted))
f.close()
```

Comment: It worked! thank you so much! i would have never guessed to add that . I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Alysson PyCrypto documentation says about `publickey.encrypt()`: [*"you should not directly encrypt data with this method"*](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#encrypt) and it recommends [PKCS#1 OAEP](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP-module.html) instead (for a code example, follow the link)

Comment: Could you please make a version for Python 3.3+?

Comment: encrypted = publickey.encrypt('encrypt this message', 32) - unsupported operand type(s) for pow(): 'str', 'int', 'int'

Comment: From the import, I presume this is using PyCryptodome. How is it then that their documentation for RSA and more specifically RSA.RsaKey does not document an encrpyt and decrypt functions. They seem strangely absent.  See link: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RsaKey

Answer (score 14):

**PKCS#1 OAEP is an asymmetric cipher based on RSA and the OAEP padding**

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP


def rsa_encrypt_decrypt():
    key = RSA.generate(2048)
    private_key = key.export_key('PEM')
    public_key = key.publickey().exportKey('PEM')
    message = input('plain text for RSA encryption and decryption:')
    message = str.encode(message)

    rsa_public_key = RSA.importKey(public_key)
    rsa_public_key = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsa_public_key)
    encrypted_text = rsa_public_key.encrypt(message)
    #encrypted_text = b64encode(encrypted_text)

    print('your encrypted_text is : {}'.format(encrypted_text))


    rsa_private_key = RSA.importKey(private_key)
    rsa_private_key = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsa_private_key)
    decrypted_text = rsa_private_key.decrypt(encrypted_text)

    print('your decrypted_text is : {}'.format(decrypted_text))
```

Comment: Is t possible to you this approach for encrypting a whole file

Comment: _RSAobj object has no 'export_key' attribute

Answer (score 12):

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import base64
import os

import six
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA


class PublicKeyFileExists(Exception): pass


class RSAEncryption(object):
    PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH = None
    PUBLIC_KEY_FILE_PATH = None

    def encrypt(self, message):
        public_key = self._get_public_key()
        public_key_object = RSA.importKey(public_key)
        random_phrase = 'M'
        encrypted_message = public_key_object.encrypt(self._to_format_for_encrypt(message), random_phrase)[0]
        # use base64 for save encrypted_message in database without problems with encoding
        return base64.b64encode(encrypted_message)

    def decrypt(self, encoded_encrypted_message):
        encrypted_message = base64.b64decode(encoded_encrypted_message)
        private_key = self._get_private_key()
        private_key_object = RSA.importKey(private_key)
        decrypted_message = private_key_object.decrypt(encrypted_message)
        return six.text_type(decrypted_message, encoding='utf8')

    def generate_keys(self):
        """Be careful rewrite your keys"""
        random_generator = Random.new().read
        key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
        private, public = key.exportKey(), key.publickey().exportKey()

        if os.path.isfile(self.PUBLIC_KEY_FILE_PATH):
            raise PublicKeyFileExists('Файл с публичным ключом существует. Удалите ключ')
        self.create_directories()

        with open(self.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH, 'w') as private_file:
            private_file.write(private)
        with open(self.PUBLIC_KEY_FILE_PATH, 'w') as public_file:
            public_file.write(public)
        return private, public

    def create_directories(self, for_private_key=True):
        public_key_path = self.PUBLIC_KEY_FILE_PATH.rsplit('/', 1)
        if not os.path.exists(public_key_path):
            os.makedirs(public_key_path)
        if for_private_key:
            private_key_path = self.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH.rsplit('/', 1)
            if not os.path.exists(private_key_path):
                os.makedirs(private_key_path)

    def _get_public_key(self):
        """run generate_keys() before get keys """
        with open(self.PUBLIC_KEY_FILE_PATH, 'r') as _file:
            return _file.read()

    def _get_private_key(self):
        """run generate_keys() before get keys """
        with open(self.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH, 'r') as _file:
            return _file.read()

    def _to_format_for_encrypt(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            return six.binary_type(value)
        for str_type in six.string_types:
            if isinstance(value, str_type):
                return value.encode('utf8')
        if isinstance(value, six.binary_type):
            return value
```

And use

```
KEYS_DIRECTORY = settings.SURVEY_DIR_WITH_ENCRYPTED_KEYS

class TestingEncryption(RSAEncryption):
    PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH = KEYS_DIRECTORY + 'private.key'
    PUBLIC_KEY_FILE_PATH = KEYS_DIRECTORY + 'public.key'


# django/flask
from django.core.files import File

class ProductionEncryption(RSAEncryption):
    PUBLIC_KEY_FILE_PATH = settings.SURVEY_DIR_WITH_ENCRYPTED_KEYS + 'public.key'

    def _get_private_key(self):
        """run generate_keys() before get keys """
        from corportal.utils import global_elements
        private_key = global_elements.request.FILES.get('private_key')
        if private_key:
            private_key_file = File(private_key)
            return private_key_file.read()

message = 'Hello мой friend'
encrypted_mes = ProductionEncryption().encrypt(message)
decrypted_mes = ProductionEncryption().decrypt(message)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is my implementation for python 3 and pycrypto

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.generate(4096)
f = open('/home/john/Desktop/my_rsa_public.pem', 'wb')
f.write(key.publickey().exportKey('PEM'))
f.close()
f = open('/home/john/Desktop/my_rsa_private.pem', 'wb')
f.write(key.exportKey('PEM'))
f.close()

f = open('/home/john/Desktop/my_rsa_public.pem', 'rb')
f1 = open('/home/john/Desktop/my_rsa_private.pem', 'rb')
key = RSA.importKey(f.read())
key1 = RSA.importKey(f1.read())

x = key.encrypt(b"dddddd",32)

print(x)
z = key1.decrypt(x)
print(z)
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to Base 64 encode the encrypted result?

Comment: Which Crypto module have you used (e.g. pycrypto)?

Comment: pycryptodome https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ is the full documentation

Comment: To base64 *encode* the result, you can `import base64` and then `base64.b64encode(encrypted)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

secret_message = b'ATTACK AT DAWN'

### First, make a key and save it
key = RSA.generate(2048)
with open( 'mykey.pem', 'wb' ) as f:
    f.write( key.exportKey( 'PEM' ))
 
### Then use key to encrypt and save our message
public_crypter = PKCS1_OAEP.new( key )
enc_data = public_crypter.encrypt( secret_message )
with open( 'encrypted.txt', 'wb' ) as f:
    f.write( enc_data )

### And later on load and decode
with open( 'mykey.pem', 'r' ) as f:
    key = RSA.importKey( f.read() )

with open( 'encrypted.txt', 'rb' ) as f:
    encrypted_data = f.read()

public_crypter =  PKCS1_OAEP.new( key )
decrypted_data = public_crypter.decrypt( encrypted_data )
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally not useful.

Comment: If you are trying to decrypt a message but getting "Incorrect decryption" error try using `PKCS1_v1_5` instead of `PKCS1_OAEP`. You also must change decrypt to include a second parameter ("sentinel"), you can use a random string.

Answer (score 1):

You can  use simple way for genarate RSA . Use rsa library

```
pip install rsa
```

Comment: Add some detail such as a link to the documentation of else this is not a helpful response. There are already too many overlapping libraries with RSA implementations so making this distinction will be valuable.

Answer (score -2):

Watch out using Crypto!!! 
It is a wonderful library but it has an issue in python3.8 'cause from the library time was removed the attribute clock(). To fix it just modify the source in `/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py`line 77 changing `t = time.clock()` int `t = time.perf_counter()`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your post is not descriptive enough to answer the OP's question. See [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).