# Import private rsa key fail

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have used the below example for encrypting and decrypting some text in python and it works:

[RSA encryption and decryption in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056762/rsa-encryption-and-decryption-in-python)

However when I write the private key to a file for future use and then import it to decrpyt some text I get:

"ValueError: RSA key format is not supported."

I have exported the private key to a file using:

```
privkey = key.exportKey()

f= open("/home/sam/samomate.pem","w+")
f.write(privkey)
f.close()
```

Try to import it using:

```
pkey = f.read()
keyDER = b64decode(pkey)
privkey=RSA.importKey(keyDER, passphrase=None)
```

I added the base64 decode on the back of googleing the error to no avail.

Any assistance on this or better alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I tried running this code and to me it works.

I didn't use the b64decode, that is not expected.

I'm not sure you've omitted any lines of code but to read a file you should use:

```
pkey_file = open(filename, "r")
pkey = f.read()
```

Then this line did not raise a ValueError:

```
privkey = RSA.importKey(pkey)
```

Comment: Sorry this was related to a very noobish mistake elsewhere in the code :-/