# How can I generate two k bit long numbers that produces their multiplication as a 2k bit long number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I mean, there's the two number, p and q for generating the n in the RSA algorithm. I want to generate the two numbers to their multiplication be 1024 bit long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RSA encryption and decryption in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056762/rsa-encryption-and-decryption-in-python)

Comment: I don't want to use built-in functions, that's why I'm asking this question this way.

Comment: generating random 512 bit primes is quite hard, not something you implement without looking at books and/or code that is already implemented; lots of math is needed to do it efficiently enough to get anything in a reasonable time

Comment: The requirements for good RSA primes are somewhat stricter than this, both individually and as a pair, to avoid known special-case factorization strategies.

Comment: Python is open source. You could check https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py (`generate()` at line 499 in particular), https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Random/random.py and its containing module.